# How to change case of method name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

While learning VBA I did a lot of copy-paste of code from the internet. At some point I have noticed that whenever I use a method which name is "Add", the VBA IDE automatically change it to "add". For example when I type `ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add` it's automatically converted to `ActiveSheet.PivotTables.add`. The same happens with `Worksheets.Add` which is changed to `Worksheets.add`. How can I restore default case of a method?

I know that VBA IDE changes variable's case accordingly to how it was declared (see: [How does one restore default case to a variable in VBA (Excel 2010)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852735/how-does-one-restore-default-case-to-a-variable-in-vba-excel-2010)). But I am not sure if it might be related to my issue.

Comment: Is this even happening when you open a blank worksheet in IDE or is it just in a particular vba project?

Comment: Is this in any way affecting performance? I have noticed some quirks where certain methods are lower-cased, but in my experience it does not matter and the code should still execute.  Are you having errors?

Comment: This is one of those obscure VBA editor quirks. I use it to my advantage since the autocorrect means I've not misspelled the name of a long variable. In combination with `Ctrl-j` (Intellisense), it can be quite useful for writing miles of code. If it's an issue, I've discussed the reasons/ a possible solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen because you have declared some variable or function or sub as  `add` in your Project (or in some add-in you might have loaded).

The VBA environment will get the last declared case representation of your variable names/function names and apply them to every instance where they occur.

E.g.

```
Function Func1()    
Dim ART As Double
ART = 1
' in one function
End Function

' Now if I type the following in another function
Function Func2()
Dim aRt as Double
End Function

' the original declaration in the first function becomes
Dim aRt As Double
aRt = 1
```

This behavior may be desirable or undesirable, but it's definitely by design.

If you want to declare variables and not want them to change case (useful for certain `Enum`s, etc.) you need to do something like

```
#If False Then
   Dim HeWhoseCaseShallNotBeChanged
   Dim ADd     ' Even methods can be "declared" here. It will have no effect on execution
#End If
```

This will work for Enums, etc. And you can declare this `compiler directive` at the top of your module page.